# Is absolute jitter bounded?

Tags: jitter

It seems that the definition of absolute jitter of the two books are the same, but they have different opinion on whether or not the absolute jitter is unbounded. I tend to agree with [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b9Qf.png), but I am not sure if I missed something from [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwsDs.png).

The following is from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b9Qf.png):

[image]

[image]

And the following is from [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwsDs.png):

[image]

[image]

- 1. [Design of CMOS Phase-Locked Loops](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108494544)
- 2. [High Speed Serdes Devices and Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-79834-9)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, discussions about jitter exclude frequency errors. In other words, the ideal waveform that you are using as reference is by definition the exact same frequency as the noisy waveform — it has exactly the same number of cycles over the measurement interval.

The graph from the first reference appears to include a frequency error in the form of the steadily rising dotted line labeled \$\omega_0 t\$. The second reference is specifically excluding this kind of error.